# Using sympy for symbolic math, the code runs forever

Tags: python, sympy

I am trying to solve simultaneous equations for x and y, I am not getting any result (code just keeps on running). I feel the error is related to using sqrt in the equations but not sure. Can someone help me figure this out?

```
from __future__ import division
from sympy import Symbol,sqrt,solve
x = Symbol('x')
y = Symbol('y')
z = Symbol('z')
a = Symbol('a')
b = Symbol('b')
c = Symbol('c')
d = Symbol('d')
e = Symbol('e')
f = Symbol('f')
g = Symbol('g')
h = Symbol('h')
print (solve((sqrt((c-a)**2+(d-b)**2)+sqrt((x-c)**2+(y-d)**2)-2*sqrt((x-a)**2+(y-b)**2),(y-b)*(e-a)-(x-a)*(f-b))  ,x,y))
```

Comment: You are not doing anything wrong, SymPy's solver is just not powerful enough. [Wolfram Alpha can do it](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20%5Bsqrt((c-a)**2%2B(d-b)**2)%2Bsqrt((x-c)**2%2B(y-d)**2)-2*sqrt((x-a)**2%2B(y-b)**2)%3D0%20,%20(y-b)*(e-a)-(x-a)*(f-b)%3D0%5D%20for%20x,%20y).  (Aside: it would be easier to declare all symbols at once with `symbols`).

Comment: Yep, Wolfram Alpha did it.

Comment: Update: Simpy solved it finally after running more than an hour.

Comment: It would even be easier to get the symbols with `from sympy.abc import x,y,z,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h` …

Comment: I recommend SageMath for this kind of thing https://www.sagemath.org/

Answer (score 1):

This is a(nother) problem were you have to rely on the A of CAS and let SymPy assist you instead of relying on SymPy (in it's current state) to do all the work. The following assumes that `eqs` is a list of the two equations you want to solve as you gave in the OP.

Notice that the 2nd equation is linear in both symbols. Solve for `y` and substitute into the first equation.

```
>>> yis = solve(eqs[1], y)[0]
>>> eq0 = eqs[0].subs(y,yis)
```

This gives an expression that has a *lot* of symbols in it and that slows things down. It also has two terms with `sqrt` that depend on `x`. Replace those arguments of the `sqrt` with Dummy symbols and then `unrad` the expression to get it in polynomial form, restore replacements and factor:

```
>>> from sympy.solvers.solvers import unrad, S
>>> reps = {i.base:Dummy() for i in eq0.atoms(Pow) if i.has(x) and i.exp==S.Half}
>>> ireps = {v:k for k,v in reps.items()}
>>> poly = unrad(eq0.xreplace(reps), *reps.values())[0].xreplace(ireps).factor()
```

Using `factor` is an expensive process to always use, but if you know the problem is going to take a long time without it, it is worth a try. In this case a quartic reduces to a product of quadratics which are easy to solve and don't require checking or simplification:

```
>>> xis = solve(poly, x)
```

There are three solutions for `x` and each of these can be substituted into the expression for `y` to get the three solutions. The solutions are large enough so they are not shown here.

```
>>> count_ops(xis)
386
```